# How to get id from option of the select tag and send to the cs class in the razor pages

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I want to get subcategory from the primary category with ajax

Html Code:

```
<select asp-for="secondCategory.CategoryId">
 @{
  foreach (var item in Model.categories)
   {
    <option value="@item.Id" class="load">@item.CatTitle</option>
   }
  }
</select>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Script Code:

```
 <script>
   $(function () {
      $('.load').on('click', function () {
$('#result').load('/Administration/Categories/SecondCategory/SecondCategory/SubCategories');
            });
    });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the `change` event listener on the select itself and get its selected value `$(this).val()`

```js
$(function () {
  $('#select').on('change', function () {
    alert($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select">
    <option value="" class="load"></option>
    <option value="123" class="load">OneTwoThree</option>
</select>
<div id="result"></div>
```